# stanley garage door opener model 2200 will not run

Tags: repair, doors, garage

my mid 1980,s stanley garage opener problem started when the 2 motor mounting bolts came out and the motor hung from gearbox when door opened - door completely opened but would not close - i replaced mounting bolts but motor does not run even with chain removed. when closer button is pressed, i hear faint hum but no attempt from motor to run - after approx 10 seconds ,clicking sound starts as if door is obstructed. any diag appreciated

Comment: Is "get a new opener" in the cards, given that that opener gave 35 years of service, and also likely won't be *serviceable* as it doesn't meet current UL safety standards for garage door openers?

Comment: It is likely that the motor burned out, or got zapped by a nearby lightning strike. 35 years is a good lifespan.

Answer (score 1):

Hello fellow internet stranger! I just found this post after experiencing a very similar problem. My Stanley 2200 garage door opener hums, but does not run.

I opened the cover and found both motor mounting screws had fallen out, allowing the motor to drop and thus disconnect itself from the motor capacitor (hence the hum-no-run condition). I also found a crack in the gearcase, which turned out to not be a problem at this time. The screws for the motor had thankfully been caught by the bottom cover. I reinstalled the screws (with some threadlocker) and reconnected the wire to the motor capacitor. It works! It may not live for another 36 years, but we'll surely get some more use out it

Hope this helps someone

Comment: Probably too late for the original asker, but useful info for anyone else who may come along. Good job locating a disconnected wire. I'm somewhat shocked that nobody here suggested that previously...